# Нужно ли устанавливать mysql server

Tags: mysql, xampp

У меня на ноуте установлен Xampp. Там есть mysql. Нужно ли устанавливать ещё отдельно mysql? И в path прописать

Comment: зачем ?? он и так бежит

Comment: я не могу зайти просто в phpmyadmin. Мне выдаёт ошибку "Необходимо обновить MySQL до версии 5.5.0 или выше" . А при запуске MySQL в Xampp Control Panel появляется сообщение Attempting to start MySQl service...и всё, не страртует

Comment: Что посоветуете?

Comment: Скачайте новуй фаил, и установите

Comment: всё, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Но необязательно. А судя по тому, что вопрос вообще возник - крайне нежелательно. Вашей квалификации для настройки скорее всего будет катастрофически недостаточно... да что настройки - даже восстановление "как было", и то будет нетривиальным.

Comment: 22:56:53  [mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
22:56:53  [mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
22:56:53  [mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
22:56:53  [mysql]     Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
22:56:53  [mysql]     Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
22:56:53  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
22:56:53  [main]     Control Panel Ready